# String pegar texto frase

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

Tenho uma frase a seguinte frase aleatória: ***Abacaxi, pera, maçã*** e queria que na variável ***var str =*** pegasse a minha frase aleatória

```html
<div class="page-header"><h1>Abacaxi, pera, maçã</h1></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">botão</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = "";
  var res = str.split(" ");
  var palavras = str.split(' ');
  var reordenado2 = [palavras.pop()].join(' ');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reordenado2;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dá pra fazer de várias formas, uma por exemplo é o `querySelector`, segue exemplo:

```html
<div class="page-header"><h1>Abacaxi, pera, maçã</h1></div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">botão</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var str = document.querySelector('div.page-header h1').innerText;
  var palavras = str.split(' ');
  var reordenado2 = palavras.reverse().join(' ');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reordenado2;
}
</script>
```

Obs: fiz algumas alterações no final, porque da forma como estava, (chamando o pop) ele pegava apenas o ultimo elemento, como sua variavel está marcada com nome de reordenado coloquei ela como reversa apenas para fazer sentido no exemplo.